# Heuristic to compute upper bound for the simple assembly line balancing problem type 2?

Tags: scheduling, heuristics, bounds

I am currently working on **SALBP-2** described as:
Given the number *m* of assembly stations, minimize the cicle time *c*.

I have done a bit of research and found the following approach to solve it:

[image]

The lower bound is clear to me but I am struggling to find a simple heuristic that computes the upper bound. What are approaches to do this?

Comment: ["A Heuristic Approach for Type 2 Assembly Line Balancing Problem"](https://www.scientific.net/AMM.789-790.1296). Don't know what its worth though.

Comment: @Kuifje thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately I don't have access to this paper.

Comment: sci*** will do the trick !

Comment: Would you see this [link](https://assembly-line-balancing.de/salbp/salome/)?